# many to many joining

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi i am currently studying sql and I have 2 one to many tables but I do not understand how to combine them to a many to many. I have a joining table.

table parent
columns parent and parent id

table child
columns child and childid

table parentchild  --(Join table selecting parents with childid)
columns parentid and childid

Here is my codes.

```
select parent.name, parentchild.childid from parent
join parentchild
on parent.parentID = parentchild.parentid

select child.name, parentchild.parentid from child
join parentchild 
on child.childID = parentchild.childid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write a single query which joins the `parent` table to the `parentchild` table and then join the `parentchild` table to the `child` table.

```
select p.name, c.name 
from parent p
join parentchild pc
    on p.parentid = pc.parentid  -- joins parent to parentchild
join child c
    on c.childID = pc.childid  -- joins parentchild to child
```